# Incrementing variable inside the curl URL parameter

Tags: bash, curl

What I want to do it use `curl` with bash variable to retrieve content length from URL with incrementing parameters.

```
for ((i=2561;i<=2563;i++))
do 
(curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' 'http:someurl.asp?q=$i)
done
```

When I do like this I always get the same content length from HTTP response. Now if I take same curl command and run outside the loop, like this:

```
curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' 'http:someurl.asp?q=2562
```

it works perfectly. I tried both for and while loops, also tried reading from file with `cat`, but it's always the same content length. What am I missing here?

Comment: You aren't closing the quotes so i don't know how it isn't causing an error. Also it's in single quotes so the parameter isn't expanded, also `$2562` will be blank unless you pass 2562 parameters to your script.

Comment: You're quoting the url in single-quotes, the `$i` won't be expanded. Moreover, if you want the result to contain a `$`, you have to escape it, ie use `"http:someurl.asp?q=\$$i"`.

Comment: The parentheses around `curl` are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks guys. 

@Aaron Yes, double quotes indeed fixed that! I spend good hour trying to figure this out. P.s.  that $ before number was just a copy mistake.

Comment: @123 Actually, `$2562` is interpreted as `${2}562` by `bash`.

Comment: @chepner Oh yeah, forgot about that.

Comment: @Thomas : Also try [\[ shellcheck \]](http://www.shellcheck.net/). Will help you identify trivial errors easiily and it also gives you a lot of suggestions regarding  how to improve the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http:someurl.asp?q=$i"
```

**Using Single quotes** ie - `'http:someurl.asp?q=$i'` usually means

1. no variable expansion
2. no command substitution
3. you get the exact stuff you put inside `''`.

Also `(process)` runs the process in a subshell which is unnecessary here.

---

**Sidenote**

The C style forloop sonstruct doesn't require you to precede variables with `$`. However when using the variables you need precede them `$`.

Answer (score 2):

A corrected code would be

```
for ((i=2561; i<=2563; i++))
do 
    curl -i -s -k  -X GET "http:someurl.asp?q=$i"
done
```

You need double quotes to allow `$1` to be expanded to the current value of `i`.